# NullPointer when dynamically creating TableLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a table view in a fragment but I am getting a `NullPointer` when I try to add the row to the layout.  `tl.addView(tr_headings);` looks to be what is causing the crash.

Thanks to anyone looking at this!

```
 public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Workouts> workout_list;
TableLayout tableLayout;

public HistoryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    String name = "bench press";
    String reps = "10";
    String weight = "150";
    String comment = "Good weight. Last rep tough";
    SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    Date d = new Date();
    String date = df.format(d);
    workout_list = new ArrayList<Workouts>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        Workouts workout = new Workouts(name, reps, weight, comment, date);
        workout_list.add(workout);
    }

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);


    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.historyTable);

    TableRow tr_headings = new TableRow(getActivity());

    TextView name_heading = new TextView(getActivity());
    TextView reps_heading = new TextView(getActivity());
    TextView weight_heading = new TextView(getActivity());
    TextView date_heading = new TextView(getActivity());
    TextView comment_heading = new TextView(getActivity());

    name_heading.setText("Exercise Name");
    reps_heading.setText("Reps");
    weight_heading.setText("Weight");
    date_heading.setText("Date");
    comment_heading.setText("Comment");

    tr_headings.addView(name_heading);
    tr_headings.addView(reps_heading);
    tr_headings.addView(weight_heading);
    tr_headings.addView(date_heading);
    tr_headings.addView(comment_heading);

    tl.addView(tr_headings); //Null pointer here!

    for(int j = 0; j < workout_list.size(); j++){

        TextView tv_name = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView tv_reps = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView tv_weight = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView tv_date = new TextView(getActivity());
        TextView tv_comment = new TextView(getActivity());

        tv_name.setText(workout_list.get(j).getExerciseName());
        tv_reps.setText(workout_list.get(j).getNumReps());
        tv_weight.setText(workout_list.get(j).getWeight());
        tv_date.setText(workout_list.get(j).getDate());
        tv_comment.setText(workout_list.get(j).getComment());

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());

        tr.addView(tv_name);
        tr.addView(tv_reps);
        tr.addView(tv_weight);
        tr.addView(tv_date);
        tr.addView(tv_comment);

        tl.addView(tr);

    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: Check if tl is null after finding it in rootView, I suspect it is not being found.

Comment: So the issue was that I was inflating the wrong fragment.  Whoops!

Comment: post your Stacktrace!